# Type mismatch with lambda

Tags: java, java-8

So the following code:

```
scoreCombiner = (Collection<ScoreContainer> subScores) -> subScores.parallelStream()
                                                                  .mapToInt(ScoreContainer::getScore)
                                                                  .reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
```

where `scoreCombiner` is a field declared as

```
private final ToIntFunction<? super List<? super ScoreContainer>> scoreCombiner;
```

is giving me the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ToIntFunction<Collection<ScoreContainer>> to ToIntFunction<? super List<? super ScoreContainer>>` which I can't understand. Collection is definitely a super-type of List, and ScoreContainer is, of course, a super-type of itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `? super List` is fine in this context.

For example this would compile:

```
ToIntFunction<? super List<?>> f = ( (Collection<?> c) -> 0 );
```

A `ToIntFunction<? super List<?>>` is a `ToIntFunction` that consumes a `List<?>`, which a `ToIntFunction<Collection<?>>` does.

The issue is the typing of the List/Collection. Recall now again, a `List<? super ScoreContainer>` is *any List that accepts a ScoreContainer*. So the trouble here is that an `IntFunction<? super List<? super ScoreContainer>>` accepts *any List that accepts a ScoreContainer*. So for example, you should be able to pass it a `Collection<Object>`.

You could only assign a lambda such as

```
... = (Collection<? super ScoreContainer> subScores) -> subScores...();
```

But the Collection your lambda is expecting is really a producer. You are expecting it to produce ScoreContainers (which you call `getScore` on). So you should be bounded by `extends`.

```
ToIntFunction<? super List<? extends ScoreContainer>> scoreCombiner;

... = (Collection<? extends ScoreContainer> subScores) -> subScores...();
```

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid now... I should've realized that the collection is a producer, even though the function is a consumer.